# How to use PipelineParameter in DatabricksStep (Python)

Tags: python, azure-databricks, azure-machine-learning-service

I've created an AML Pipeline with a single DatabricksStep. I've need to pass a parameter to the Databricks notebook when I run the published pipeline.

When I run the published pipeline, the Databricks steps always take the default value of the PipelineParameter, no matter what value I choose when I submit the pipeline.

Here the code:

```py
start_date_param = PipelineParameter(name="StartDate", default_value='2022-01-19')

# Define data ingestion step
data_loading_step = DatabricksStep(
        name="Data Loading",
        existing_cluster_id=db_cluster_id,
        notebook_path=data_loading_path,
        run_name="Loading raw data",
        notebook_params={
            'StartDate': start_date_param,
        },
        compute_target=dbricks_compute,
        instance_pool_id=instance_pool_id,
        num_workers=num_workers,
        allow_reuse=False
    )
```

And this is the Databricks notebook:

```
dbutils.widgets.text("StartDate", "", "StartDate(YYYY-MM-DD)")
```

The default value of StartDate is 2022-01-19.Even though I set the StartDate parameter to '2021-01-19' the Databricks notebook still takes 2022-01-19 as StartDate.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help,

G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution of the problem. I hope it can be of help to someone.
It works if you set all the parameter name and widget name in lower case.

```py
start_date_param = PipelineParameter(name="start_date", default_value='2022-01-19')

# Define data ingestion step
data_loading_step = DatabricksStep(
        name="Data Loading",
        existing_cluster_id=db_cluster_id,
        notebook_path=data_loading_path,
        run_name="Loading raw data",
        notebook_params={
            'start_date': start_date_param,
        },
        compute_target=dbricks_compute,
        instance_pool_id=instance_pool_id,
        num_workers=num_workers,
        allow_reuse=False
    )
```

```
dbutils.widgets.text("start_date", "", "start_date(YYYY-MM-DD)")
```

Comment: Great that you find your answer! You can accept your own answer to let others know that this question is closed.